# python sort dictionary items by value and then key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, items

All,

I'm having difficulty sorting a dictionary by value and then printing.

My object (dataSet) looks like the following...

```
dict_items([(0, {'studentName': 'dan', 'Score': 80.0}), (1, {'studentName': 'rob', 'Score': 92.0})])
```

I would like to sort by Score and print, but I am failing miserably. I used the following method as advised to sort by StudentName, if it is of help.

```
entries = sorted([(dataSet[entry]['studentName'], dataSet[entry]['Score']) for entry in dataSet])
  for name, score in entries:
    print(('Student: {} -- Score: {}%'.format(name, score)))
```

Comment: can we see the contents of dataSet?

Comment: Sorting by score and then names probably isn't going to work unless you are going to have ranges of scores that you can sort the names in.

Comment: @AyushShanker edited to make that more obvious.

Comment: @SirParselot Thinking about it, I am happy by simply sorting by Score. Python is not my domain and beggars can't be choosers!

Comment: It is not possible to sort a dict, only to get a representation of a dict that is sorted. Dicts are inherently orderless, but other types, such as lists and tuples, are not. So you need a sorted representation, which will be a list—probably a list of tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyDict = {0: {'Score': 80.0, 'studentName': 'dan'},
          1: {'Score': 92.0, 'studentName': 'rob'},
          2: {'Score': 10.0, 'StudentName': 'xyz'}}
```

This returns the list of key-value pairs in the dictionary, sorted by value from highest to lowest:

```
sorted(MyDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

For the dictionary sorted by key, use the following:

```
sorted(MyDict.items(), reverse=True)
```

The return is a list of tuples because dictionaries themselves can't be sorted.

This can be both printed or sent into further computation.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a list of keys ordered by Score value:

```
d = {0: {'Score': 80.0, 'studentName': 'dan'},
     1: {'Score': 92.0, 'studentName': 'rob'},
     2: {'Score': 10.0, 'studentName': 'xyz'}}

sorted(d, key=lambda k: d[k]['Score'])
```

produces

```
[2, 0, 1]
```

Otherwise, you can use an ordered dictionary

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['Score']))
```

which gives you

```
OrderedDict([(0, {'Score': 80.0, 'studentName': 'dan'}), (1, {'Score': 92.0, 'studentName': 'rob'})])
```

that you can print out nicely

```
for v in od.values():
    print(v['Score'], v['studentName'])

10.0 xyz
80.0 dan
92.0 rob
```

Comment: would this suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

assuming your object is a `list` of `tuples` of `dicts` (closest interpretation I can reach via the data given), This would suffice:

```
>>> dict_items = [(0, {'Score': 80.0, 'studentName': 'dan'}), (1, {'Score': 92.0, 'studentName': 'rob'
})]
>>> sorted(dict_items, key=lambda x: x[1]['Score'])
# [(0, {'Score': 80.0, 'studentName': 'dan'}), (1, {'Score': 92.0, 'studentName': 'rob'
})]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is below, maybe someone needs :

```
d = {0: {'Score': 80.0, 'studentName': 'dan'},
     1: {'Score': 92.0, 'studentName': 'rob'},
     2: {'Score': 10.0, 'StudentName': 'xyz'}}

sorted(d, cmp = lambda a,b: cmp(d[a]['Score'],d[b]['Score']))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use:

```
 def comp(x,y):
    if x[1]['Score'] != y[1]['Score']:
        return 1 if x[1]['Score'] > y[1]['Score'] else -1
    elif x[1]['studentName'] < y[1]['studentName']:
        return -1
    elif x[1]['studentName'] > y[1]['studentName']:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

then

```
sorted(dict_items, comp)
```

For example for

```
dict_items = [(0, {'Score': 80.0, 'studentName': 'dan'}),
              (1, {'Score': 92.0, 'studentName': 'rob'}),
              (2, {'Score': 70.0, 'studentName': 'foo'})]
```

it gives:

```
[(2, {'Score': 70.0, 'studentName': 'foo'}), (0, {'Score': 80.0, 'studentName': 'dan'}),
 (1, {'Score': 92.0, 'studentName': 'rob'})]
```

But **beware**: your question title was about *dictionnary* items. The answer is coherent with the code in the question but only sort a list of tuples. If you really have a dict `d`, you should use `sorted(d.items())`